# Android set temporary property

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to set some flag that my application can check when a certain condition occurs.  I want this 'flag' to be removed automatically when the system reboots.  I need this flag to persist over multiple application restarts.

My first attempt was to try `System.setProperty("flag", "true")` but I found that when I do `System.getProperty()` after an app restart, this flag is not set any longer.

Another thought I had was creating a file when the condition occurs.  Then when the application restarts I can check if this file exists.  And I can use a BootReceiver to clear the file when the system reboots.  The problem with this is that the check for this file can happen before the BootReceiver is executed which is not what I want.

Are there any simpler mechanisms I can use you can think of?  I had a look at SharedPreferences and internal storage using cache files but I don't think they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a boot broadcast receiver along with SharedPreferences. 
When system boots, reset your variable and save it to SharedPreferences.

Add this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and also this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Last you need to create broadcastReceiver:

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mSharedPreferences.putBoolean("yourVariable", true).apply();
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  Read the third paragraph.  The problem with this is that the check for the flag is at the start of the application and that can happen before the BootReceiver has executed.

Comment: my bad, sorry, but i think that this is the only way to make it (without root permissions), can you please explain how can this check occurs before you get signal from boot receiver?

Comment: The check occurs in Application.onCreate() which gets executed before BootReceiver.